Is it Mi Yodeya's job to vet the Moshiach?
I vote no. In my year and a half here, I've come across at least half a dozen people coming claiming to be, or know, the Moshiach, and asking us to vet, help or learn from such individual. E.g
I vote that this is permanently off topic!

Plus, they're all wrong.  Elvis is the mashiach.  Y'chi hamelech!
